# Accomplishing 'Long Polling' to monitor events - REST or STREAMING API?

Tags: rest-api, event, streaming-api

My use case is to be notified of any new documents uploaded to the account - { I could potentially use the StreamingApi but my entire infrastructure is based on REST, while the StreamingApi uses Bayeux protocol} - do you think 'updated/deleted' are the best choices for the same.

I saw that Box has something called Long Polling - [developers.box.com/using-long-polling-to-monitor-events/](http://developers.box.com/using-long-polling-to-monitor-events/) .. is there a REST equivalent of the same in Salesforce ?

Comment: the salesforce equivalent is the streaming api.

Answer (score 4):

Streaming API is long polling for salesforce; normal polling won't work here. Using the normal REST API's updated/deleted functions work once per call, so you won't have real-time status updates. On the other hand, the Streaming API has its limits as well, so if events are constantly generated, you may run into those limits.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a pilot for a gRPC-based PubSub API.
(salesforce is still supporting the Bayeux approach, but gRPC did not exist when the Streaming API was released, and has since become much more popular)